# NotSupportedException when converting an IQueryable<object>

Tags: c#, linq, exception, iqueryable

When I do this :

```
    var db = new NotentoolEntities();
    IQueryable<GroupOfBranches> queryGOB = db.tabGroupOfBranches.Cast<GroupOfBranches>().Where(x => x.intGroupID.Equals(ID));
    List<GroupOfBranches> GOB = new List<GroupOfBranches>(queryGOB); //here is the error
```

I've got the following error :

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
```

Comment: there might be problem with Equals function which is not supported by entityframework..

Comment: Calling `ToList()` after `Where()` might be clearer

Comment: My error is at the third line, but I tried to replace the Equals too and I got the same error

Comment: Why are you casting to GroupOfBranches?

Comment: Because I need to return this object

Comment: What exactly is the type returned by tabGroupOfBranches? What kinds of constructors does GroupOfBranches have? Please add more code to the question to explain the types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might consider to change your code to

```
using (var db = new NotentoolEntities())
   {
      var GOB = db.tabGroupOfBranches.Where(x => x.intGroupID == ID).Select(y => new GroupOfBranches
          {
              /// here specify your fields
          }).AsNoTracking().ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I suppose that the underlying LINQ provider cannot convert call to Equals to anything it knows about.

Use == operator instead. That will end up in a different expression tree, which can be translated.

```
var db = new NotentoolEntities();
IQueryable<GroupOfBranches> queryGOB =
    db.tabGroupOfBranches.Cast<GroupOfBranches>().Where(x => x.intGroupID == ID));
List<GroupOfBranches> GOB = new List<GroupOfBranches>(queryGOB);
```

If GroupOfBranches is derived class from whatever the type is returned by tabGroupOfBranches, then you should probably use OfType, rather than Cast.

Otherwise, Cast might go after Where, and be replaced with a Select which creates instances of GroupOfBranches class explicitly.

Comment: Does it still happen? That is where the query is executed and I would expect to see the error manifesting in the third line.

Comment: Yes it still happen

Comment: Try to execute queryGOB.ToList() without anything else. That will limit the options.

Comment: Do you have the stack trace? In which method exactly did the exception occur?

Comment: I have updated the answer with suggestions regarding Cast. If it wasn't Where, then it's the Cast that fails.